# Xpath para Google Calc en Columnas

Tags: xml, google-hoja-de-cálculo, xpath, google-drive

Lo quiero usar en Google Calc con la función IMPORTXML

Estoy haciendo pruebas en https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

El XML sería el siguiente:

```
    <players xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xxxxxx" timestamp="111111" serverId="172">
<player id="1" name="A" status="a"/>
<player id="2" name="B" status="a"/>
<player id="3" name="C" status="a"/>
<player id="4" name="D" status="a"/>
<player id="5" name="E" status="a"/>
<player id="6" name="F" status="v" class="172"/>
<player id="7" name="G" status="i"/>
<player id="8" name="H" status="vIb"/>
<player id="9" name="I" status="v" class="145"/>
<player id="10" name="J" status="I"/>
<player id="11" name="K" status="vi"/>
<player id="12" name="L" status="v" class="267"/>
</players>
```

Necesito que usando la función anteriormente mencionada en Google Calc me muestre id, name, status y class en la primera, segunda, tercera y cuarta columna respectivamente. Sólo he conseguido que me muestre todo en la primera columna pero en filas distintas con //player/@*. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La página que propones: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html
NO sirve para acceder online con los datos de prueba que indicas. Es para probar diferentes expresiones xpath con los datos y comandos que quieras, pero solo desde dentro de esa misma página web.

Así que contestare con el fichero de ejemplo disponible online  en
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml

Si colocas en una celda de la primera fila de una
Google Spreadsheets

esta formula:

=importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml"; CONCATENATE("//book["; ROW(); "]"))

y la copias en las filas 1, 2, 3, 4, y 5
Obtendrás:

```
Everyday Italian    Giada De Laurentiis 2005        30.00               
Harry Potter        J K. Rowling        2005        29.99               
XQuery Kick Start   James McGovern      Per Bothner Kurt Cagle  James Linn  Vaidyanathan 
Nagarajan   2003    49.99
Learning XML        Erik T. Ray         2003        39.95               
#N/A
```

Dado que en la formula ROW() proporciona el número de fila donde hemos pegado la formula. Y en la expresión XPATH uso ese valor para indicar el nº de registro en la fila 1 aparecerán los datos del registro 1, en la fila 2 los datos del 2º registro y así sucesivamente. El fichero de muestra solo tiene 4 registros.
Por eso en la quinta fila tenemos #N/A

En cada columna aparece un campo del registro correspondiente.
Pero como el registro 3 no tiene el mismo formato que el 1, 2 y 4 (el 3 tienen varios autores) no coinciden las columnas.
Imagino que ahora no tendrás problemas para ajustar este ejemplo a tus necesidades.

Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Más claro este otro ejemplo. Para ver los datos XML sobre el que trabajamos visitar: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml . Ponemos estas formulas en las celdas de la hoja de calculo:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[1]/title") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[1]/author[1]") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[1]/year") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[1]/price") |
| 2 | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[2]/title") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[2]/author[1]") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[2]/year") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[2]/price") |
| 3 | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[3]/title") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[3]/author[1]") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[3]/year") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[3]/price") |
| 4 | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[4]/title") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[4]/author[1]") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[4]/year") | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[4]/price") |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | =importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml";"//book[2]/@category")) |  |  |  |

Y obtendremos esta salida:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Everyday Italian | Giada De Laurentiis | 2005 | 30.00 |
| 2 | Harry Potter | J K. Rowling | 2005 | 29.99 |
| 3 | XQuery Kick Start | James McGovern | 2003 | 49.99 |
| 4 | Learning XML | Erik T. Ray | 2003 | 39.95 |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | children |  |  |  |

Explicitar las 3 variantes de expresiones Xpath utilizadas.
Tipo A1: //book[1]/title
Devuelve el ELEMENTO "title" del primer book: Everyday Italian

Tipo B3: //book[3]/author[1]
Devuelve el ELEMENTO primer author del tercer book: James McGovern
Si solo hay un autor o hay más de uno no importa solo devuelve el primero de ellos.

Tipo A6: //book[2]/@category
Devuelve el ATRIBUTO category del segundo book

Con los datos de ejemplo que proporcionas los player no tienen ELEMENTO (contenido) pero sí tienen atributos:. Así que si he entendido bien la consulta las expresiones que buscas serian de este tipo A6. En concreto:

```
    =importxml("https://servidor/fichero.xml";"//player[1]/@id")  
    =importxml("https://servidor/fichero.xml";"//player[1]/@name)  
    =importxml("https://servidor/fichero.xml";"//player[1]/@status)
```

Suerte